# Filter an array of object based on weekly filters and return each week data

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object which coming from the back-end and I want to filter by created date based on the week start at specifics created date weekend at specifics created date, example here I have three weeks data and I want to filter each week data and push each weekly data to a new array, please i need help on this

```
[
  {id: "0ee1a179-2f87-4f11-916c-1341e3d9bcf3", adspend: 1500, createdAt: "25-02-2019"},
  {id: "44b0172a-f9e4-4561-b903-fa6b18ee055c", adspend: 4278, createdAt: "27-02-2019"},
  {id: "5b66a486-56ff-41e9-9969-e0d820f8521c", adspend: 3966, createdAt: "27-02-2019"},
  {id: "88cb602f-63ef-40c7-a30e-cf9dbfd95cc5", adspend: 47898, createdAt: "28-02-2019"},
  {id: "3251d613-4d17-4900-b394-2cd8c34f8bf7", adspend: 1536, createdAt: "28-02-2019"},
  {id: "c78dfb97-0e2c-4937-b154-0808a8650f08", adspend: 75317, createdAt: "01-03-2019"},
  {id: "2eea6d91-5444-4926-8010-df58e59b930b", adspend: 2194, createdAt: "01-03-2019"},
  {id: "631af893-b1f6-4012-800a-df27f387232b", adspend: 670, createdAt: "02-03-2019"},

  {id: "44b0172a-f9e4-4561-b903-fa6b18ee055c", adspend: 4278, createdAt: "04-03-2019"},
  {id: "5b66a486-56ff-41e9-9969-e0d820f8521c", adspend: 3966, createdAt: "04-03-2019"},
  {id: "88cb602f-63ef-40c7-a30e-cf9dbfd95cc5", adspend: 47898, createdAt: "06-03-2019"},
  {id: "3251d613-4d17-4900-b394-2cd8c34f8bf7", adspend: 1536, createdAt: "06-03-2019"},
  {id: "c78dfb97-0e2c-4937-b154-0808a8650f08", adspend: 75317, createdAt: "09-03-2019"},
  {id: "2eea6d91-5444-4926-8010-df58e59b930b", adspend: 2194, createdAt: "09-03-2019"},
  {id: "631af893-b1f6-4012-800a-df27f387232b", adspend: 670, createdAt: "09-03-2019"},

  {id: "022dab43-cc38-451f-bfd9-a012de5a6f9f", adspend: 603, createdAt: "11-03-2019"},
  {id: "44b0172a-f9e4-4561-b903-fa6b18ee055c", adspend: 4278, createdAt: "12-03-2019"},
  {id: "88cb602f-63ef-40c7-a30e-cf9dbfd95cc5", adspend: 47898, createdAt: "13-03-2019"},
  {id: "c78dfb97-0e2c-4937-b154-0808a8650f08", adspend: 75317, createdAt: "13-03-2019"},
  {id: "2eea6d91-5444-4926-8010-df58e59b930b", adspend: 2194, createdAt: "14-03-2019"},
  {id: "631af893-b1f6-4012-800a-df27f387232b", adspend: 670, createdAt: "14-03-2019"},
]
```

Comment: use `array.filter((obj)=>{ return obj.createdAt==dateToBeMatched})`

Comment: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: that  is exactly the issues I am facing here because date to be matched need to come from the array, the example from 25-02-2019 to 01-03-2019 is a week data so that is the dates which need to be matched and to apply this on every iteral to calculate  which date is week started and which date is week ended so it can filter based on the date and return each week  data

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the week for each date and using that week with the year as key, create an array with all the common week data.

```js
let data = [{ id: "0ee1a179-2f87-4f11-916c-1341e3d9bcf3", adspend: 1500, createdAt: "25-02-2019" }, { id: "44b0172a-f9e4-4561-b903-fa6b18ee055c", adspend: 4278, createdAt: "27-02-2019" }, { id: "5b66a486-56ff-41e9-9969-e0d820f8521c", adspend: 3966, createdAt: "27-02-2019"}, { id: "88cb602f-63ef-40c7-a30e-cf9dbfd95cc5", adspend: 47898, createdAt: "28-02-2019" }, { id: "3251d613-4d17-4900-b394-2cd8c34f8bf7", adspend: 1536, createdAt: "28-02-2019" }, { id: "c78dfb97-0e2c-4937-b154-0808a8650f08", adspend: 75317, createdAt:"01-03-2019" }, { id: "2eea6d91-5444-4926-8010-df58e59b930b", adspend: 2194, createdAt: "01-03-2019" }, { id: "631af893-b1f6-4012-800a-df27f387232b", adspend: 670, createdAt: "02-03-2019" }, { id: "44b0172a-f9e4-4561-b903-fa6b18ee055c", adspend: 4278,createdAt: "04-03-2019" }, { id: "5b66a486-56ff-41e9-9969-e0d820f8521c", adspend: 3966, createdAt: "04-03-2019" }, { id: "88cb602f-63ef-40c7-a30e-cf9dbfd95cc5", adspend: 47898, createdAt: "06-03-2019" }, { id: "3251d613-4d17-4900-b394-2cd8c34f8bf7", adspend:1536, createdAt: "06-03-2019" }, { id: "c78dfb97-0e2c-4937-b154-0808a8650f08", adspend: 75317, createdAt: "09-03-2019" }, { id: "2eea6d91-5444-4926-8010-df58e59b930b", adspend: 2194, createdAt: "09-03-2019" }, { id: "631af893-b1f6-4012-800a-df27f387232b",adspend: 670, createdAt: "09-03-2019" }, { id: "022dab43-cc38-451f-bfd9-a012de5a6f9f", adspend: 603, createdAt: "11-03-2019" }, { id: "44b0172a-f9e4-4561-b903-fa6b18ee055c", adspend: 4278, createdAt: "12-03-2019" }, { id: "88cb602f-63ef-40c7-a30e-cf9dbfd95cc5",adspend: 47898, createdAt: "13-03-2019" }, { id: "c78dfb97-0e2c-4937-b154-0808a8650f08", adspend: 75317, createdAt: "13-03-2019" }, { id: "2eea6d91-5444-4926-8010-df58e59b930b", adspend: 2194, createdAt: "14-03-2019" }, { id: "631af893-b1f6-4012-800a-df27f387232b",adspend: 670, createdAt: "14-03-2019" }, ],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
      let weekNumber = moment(o.createdAt, "DD-MM-YYYY").isoWeek(),
          key = weekNumber + "_" + o.createdAt.slice(-4);
      r[key] = r[key] || [];
      r[key].push({...o});
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ReaganSCOFIELD you can [mark an answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark next to the answer. You get 2 reputations and the answerer gets 15 (You have asked 7 questions and haven't accepted any answer)